# How to link against a local Rust library? (similar to npm link)

Tags: node.js, git, rust, rust-crates, rust-cargo

When developing a library in node,
if you wish to develop against a library that only exists locally,
before you `npm publish`,
you can use `npm link /path/to/other/node_library`.

What is the equivalent of this for Rust?
How do you create another a foo executable that links to bar library,
without pushing bar library to a git remote first?

[The official rust tutorial](http://doc.rust-lang.org/tutorial.html#crates-and-the-module-system) shows how to do this using raw `rustc`,
how can this be done in `Cargo.toml`?

(The [cargo documentation](http://crates.io/manifest.html) shows you how to build a lib,
but now how to link to one that doesn't have a remote repository.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025972/470749

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to use git `file:` URL if your dependency is in a local git repo:

```
[dependencies.local_dep]
git = "file:/some/local/path"
```

There is also a very useful feature when you want to use your own local copy of some package. You can specify a path to such package in `~/.cargo/config` file:

```
package-name = "/path/to/package"
```

With this configuration when some other package (let's name it `a`) requires `package-name`, regardless of what is declared in `a` manifest about `package-name` location, `package-name` will be build from the source tree specified in this config file. This is useful when you need to test your changes in a library which other projects depend on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but both of these suggestions do not work when the local dependency and the executable that link to it link against the same 3rd party dependencies, I get an error when running `cargo update`: `At the moment, Cargo only supports a single source for a particular package name (Dependency { name: nickel, source_id: https://github.com/nickel-org/nickel.rs.git, req: *, transitive: true, only_match_name: false }).`

Comment: I believe `package-name` is now `paths` and is an array as per the docs at http://doc.crates.io/config.html#configuration-keys

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
[dependencies.local_dep]
path = "some/local/path"
```

Check out https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx-rs/blob/master/Cargo.toml for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this suggestion does not work when the local dependency and the executable that link to it link against the same 3rd party dependencies, I get an error when running `cargo update`: `At the moment, Cargo only supports a single source for a particular package name (Dependency { name: nickel, source_id: https://github.com/nickel-org/nickel.rs.git, req: *, transitive: true, only_match_name: false }).`

Comment: [Here](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#path-dependencies)'s the official Cargo doc about `path`.

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-dependencies-section contains an example of doing this with the `path` field (the `geometry` crate):

```
[package]
# ...

[dependencies]
hammer = { version = "0.5.0", git = "https://github.com/wycats/hammer.rs" }
color = { git = "https://github.com/bjz/color-rs" }
geometry = { path = "crates/geometry" }
```