# How to use a local unpublished crate?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I've made a library:

```
cargo new my_lib
```

and I want to use that library in a different program:

```
cargo new my_program --bin
```

```
extern crate my_lib;

fn main {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

what do I need to do to get this to work?

They aren't in the same project folder.

```
.
├── my_lib
└── my_program
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

I thought I'd be able to override the path as per the [Cargo guide](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html), but it states

> You cannot use this feature to tell Cargo how to find local unpublished crates.

This is when using the latest stable version of Rust (1.3).

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Add a dependency section to your executable's **Cargo.toml** and specify the path:

```
[dependencies.my_lib]
path = "../my_lib"
```

or the equivalent alternate TOML:

```
[dependencies]
my_lib = { path = "../my_lib" }
```

Check out the [Cargo docs for specifying dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) for more detail, like how to use a git repository instead of a local path.

Comment: Is there a way to use a local crate myself (for development) while leaving Cargo.toml referring to crates.io so others can also build my code?

Comment: Not possible by default at the moment. You can however work on a local branch, replace Cargo.toml with local dependency references (or mixed references), and before you merge or during, revert to or keep the main Cargo.toml file.

Comment: @DavidRoundy if you're still looking for an answer, it's now possible to do what you're asking. You can specify both `version` and `path` for a dependency and it will strip the `path` part out when you publish it :)

Comment: Detailed documentation is available at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies

Comment: Is it possible to do the same but with `git` instead of `version`? Something like this `my_lib = { path = "...", git = "..." }` so that I can use my local copy during development and the remote git when someone clones the repo and tries to compile the program?

Comment: There should really be a better way to do this other than using a relative path, which is something which could change. If one crate depends on another, and both are in the same *workspace* is there no way to specify a dependency without using a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an equivalent to `mvn install`. While this question is not quite a duplicate of my original question, anyone who stumbles across my original question and follows the link here will find a more complete answer.

The answer is "there is no equivalent to `mvn install` because you have to hard-code the path in the Cargo.toml file which will probably be wrong on someone else's computer, but you can get pretty close."

The existing answer is a bit brief and I had to flail around for a bit longer to actually get things working, so here's more detail:

```
/usr/bin/cargo run --color=always --package re5 --bin re5
   Compiling re5 v0.1.0 (file:///home/thoth/art/2019/radial-embroidery/re5)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `embroidery_stitcher`
 --> re5/src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use embroidery_stitcher;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `embroidery_stitcher` in the root
```

`rustc --explain E0432` includes this paragraph that echos Shepmaster's answer:

> Or, if you tried to use a module from an external crate, you may have missed
>   the `extern crate` declaration (which is usually placed in the crate root):
>
> ```
> extern crate core; // Required to use the `core` crate
>
> use core::any;
> ```

Switching from `use` to `extern crate` got me this:

```
/usr/bin/cargo run --color=always --package re5 --bin re5
   Compiling embroidery_stitcher v0.1.0 (file:///home/thoth/art/2019/radial-embroidery/embroidery_stitcher)
warning: function is never used: `svg_header`
 --> embroidery_stitcher/src/lib.rs:2:1
  |
2 | fn svg_header(w: i32, h: i32) -> String
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(dead_code)] on by default

   Compiling re5 v0.1.0 (file:///home/thoth/art/2019/radial-embroidery/re5)
error[E0603]: function `svg_header` is private
 --> re5/src/main.rs:8:19
  |
8 |     let mut svg = embroidery_stitcher::svg_header(100,100);
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I had to slap a `pub` on the front of that function

```
pub fn svg_header(w: i32, h: i32) -> String
```

Now it works.

Comment: And now this answer is a miniature article: http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/rust-external-libraries/

Comment: Also, `extern crate` may only be used in edition 2015 or in other cases, since cargo itself already links these crates.