# Unresolved import when importing from a local crate with a main.rs file

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have included a library as a submodule in my program. The structure looks like this:

```
.
├── my_lib/
│    ├── Cargo.toml
│    └── src/
│         ├── lib/
│         │    ├── mod.rs
│         │    └── foo.rs
│         └── main.rs
├── src/
│    └── main.rs
└── Cargo.toml
```

In my program's `Cargo.toml` file I have added the dependency following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025972/5837583):

```ini
[dependencies]
my_lib = { path = "./my_lib" }
```

However I'm not able to use this library inside my program, I'm a bit new to Rust and this import system is very confusing to me. I've tried this in `main.rs`:

```rust
use my_lib::foo;
```

But I get an `unresolved import 'my_lib'` error.

Comment: why isn't the source of my_lib directly in `my_lib/src` ? I would expect `my_lib/src/lib.rs`. What's that `lib/` directory ?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what the contents of the `Cargo.toml` files are. You also don't show any Rust files (and their contents) inside of `my_lib`. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Following edit: A lib usually has a `lib.rs` file, not a `main.rs` one. That's probably your first problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A crate can be **either** a library or an executable, not both. Your `my_lib` contains a *main.rs* file, which means Cargo will treat it as an executable file. You cannot import from an executable.

You will need to restructure your code. Perhaps you actually meant for `my_lib` to be a library, in which case it should have a top-level *lib.rs*. You probably want to:

- delete *my_lib/src/main.rs*
- move *my_lib/src/lib/mod.rs* to *my_lib/src/lib.rs*
- move *my_lib/src/lib/foo.rs* to *my_lib/src/foo.rs*

See also:

- [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/rust-package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary)