# Is there a way to specify that one executable depends on another in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project with two executables:

```
src
└── bin
    ├── app.rs
    └── tool.rs
```

The `tool` program is run as a subprocess of `app`. (The separation is needed because `tool` is run with different permissions than `app`.)

To run `app` I need to first ensure that `tool` has been built, so I currently do something like this:

```
cargo build && cargo run --bin app
```

Ideally I would be able to add something to my `Cargo.toml` so that it knows that `app` depends on `tool` being built so that I could just run this:

```
cargo run --bin app
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Would [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025887/how-to-use-a-local-unpublished-crate) be what you're looking for? It's based on [this part](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies) of the cargo docs. Should handle building `tool` and all of it's dependencies when you run `app`.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, without hacky approaches, but there is some work in progress getting close: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9096