# Can't find local crate specified in Cargo.toml even though main.rs exists

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I am trying to understand how to use local crates. I have the same problem as specified in [How to use a local unpublished crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025887/how-to-use-a-local-unpublished-crate), but the answers do not solve my problem. File structure:

```
|--my_program
|   |--Cargo.toml  
|   |--src
|      |--main.rs
|
|--my_lib
    |--Cargo.toml  
    |--src
       |--main.rs
```

my_lib/main.rs :

```rust
fn main() {}
```

my_lib/Cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "my_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["test"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
```

my_program/main.rs :

```rust
fn main() {}
```

my_program/Cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "my_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["test"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
my_lib = { path = "../my_lib" }
```

Out:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `my_lib`
```

Windows 10, rustc 1.47

I can use std:: crates as well as download crates like clap, but i can't figure our how to use a local crate. I have also tried "use" instead of "extern crate", which is supposed to do the same, but I also get an error (error[E0432]: unresolved import `my_lib`) saying no'my_lib' external crate.

Comment: are you sure ? check twice the lib name in your toml. also be sure that "my_lib" IS a lib that HAVE a lib.rs file

Comment: A crate with `main.rs` creates a binary, not a library. You cannot import from a binary. Rename `my_lib/main.rs` to `my_lib/lib.rs` (or create it with `cargo new --lib`).